# What is the meaning of $\frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}=0$ in this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Given $L=p \log{(p+r)}$ where $p \in [0, 1], r \in [-1, 1]$, I need to show that $L$ is maximum when $r=0$ for any $p$.

I think the solution should be degenerate in the direction of $p$, and gave it a try:
\begin{align*}
\textrm{Set } \frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}&=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left[ \log{(p+r)}+\frac{p}{p+r} \right] &= 0\\
\frac{1}{p+r}-\frac{p}{(p+r)^{2}} &= 0\\
\frac{r}{(p+r)^{2}} &= 0 \implies r=0
\end{align*}
And $\frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}<0$ when $r<0$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}>0$ when $r>0$, which reminds me of the first derivative and concavity tests.

How should I interpret this result? What do $\frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}$, $\frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}=0$, $\frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}<0$, $\frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial p \partial r}>0$ even mean?

Comment: One note is that function has whole regions of undefined territory, since you need $p+r>0$.  In particular,  it is not defined at p=0, r=0,  so r=0 certainly isn't the maximum value when p=0!